# The Lord is tri-yuga?

Tags: vishnu, yuga, kali-yuga, kalki

[The Lord is tri-yuga](http://vanisource.org/wiki/SB_3.16.22)

The above translation states that the Lord descends in three yugas: Satya, Treta, and Dvapara. Or rather, the translation doesn't say that, but the commentary does. This makes no logical sense to me, because the Satya Yuga seems to be the age when everything is perfect, thereby non-necessitating an Incarnation of the Lord to fight demons and atheists.

For example, the "earlier" Incarnation of the Lord is Matsya, but if we correlate the Satya Yuga with the "Garden of Eden" (i.e. when everything is perfect), even the Matsya Incarnation would occur when Manu (i.e. Adam) had already left Eden (when the Satya Age had ended). Therefore the Manu that Matsya helps would be equivalent to Noah, but this wouldn't be in the Satya Yuga, it would be in the... Treta Yuga?

Furthermore we can't even really locate a pure Vaishnava Incarnation like Rama and Krishna as far back as the Satya Age anyways. (We only have animal Incarnations like Matsya, Kurma, and Varaha. Perhaps Narasimha would count as a "Perfect Incarnation," but even so, why would the Lord incarnate in the Satya Yuga?) It would seem to make more sense that the Lord would incarnate in the following three ages: Treta, Dvapara, and Kali, since there would be actual work to be done in those ages, both "intellectual," and "material."

But if everything is perfect... why an Incarnation of the Lord?

This makes way more sense to me:

1. Rama in Treta
2. Krishna in Dvapara
3. Kalki in Kali

We can't really equivocate the Buddha with a "personal" Incarnation of the Lord because he doesn't even teach a theistic doctrine, rather he seems to represent the gradual decline of theism after its peak, which reaches its perfect expression in the Mahabharata (with Krishna). If we consider the Lord as Time, Time definitely reaches its full stature in the Krishna Incarnation, specifically because Krishna is involved in all aspects of life, material and spiritual, the Buddha seems to represent old age and death, this is probably why Krishna is regarded as the purnavatara. Even Krishna Himself states: "I am Time, grown to full stature." After the peak, there can only be the decline.

But it also seems like Kalki is explicitly theistic and IN the Kali Age, so it would make some sense for Kalki to be a personal Incarnation of the Lord. [This website](https://www.narach.com/) has some good information, particularly [this page](https://www.narach.com/philosophy/incarnations_and_ages_of_time.htm). [This](http://harekrsna.com/philosophy/incarnations/dasavatara.htm) also makes sense.

> Sometimes Vishnu descends personally, sometimes he sends his bonafide representative in the form of his son or servant, and sometimes he comes himself in a disguised form.

For example, personal descents would include: Rama, Krishna, and Kalki.

Representative in the form of a servant, maybe Muhammad (s.a.w.). Representative in the form of his son, maybe Jesus. As a disguised Incarnation, maybe ‘Ali. (There are some sects of Islam that believe ‘Ali was God, *veiled* by Muhammad (s.a.w.).)

Thoughts?

For example, it's easy to provide correlations between Islam and Hinduism, Islam is the youngest religion and Hinduism is the oldest.

In all three "personal" Incarnations of the Lord, he always comes in "catur-bhuja" form, meaning he always comes with three co-incarnations or relatives who aid him in his fight against atheism. When he was Rama, he came with Laksmana, Bharata, and Satrughna. When he was Krishna, he came with Balarāma, Pradyumna, and Aniruddha. When he was Kalki, he came with Kavi, Sumanta, and Prajna.

This four-armed form doesn't occur for Incarnations like the Buddha, for example. Maybe the Buddha isn't even the "Lord of the World," but at that point we'd be bringing Theosophy into this.

Even in the Islamic "Incarnation" of ‘Ali, we find the Lord disguised by Muhammad (s.a.w.), literally veiled (i.e. hijab).

The most explicit Incarnation is Krishna, but even Krishna states that He is "veiled by His Divine Maya, unknown to the world."

For example, in Gaudiya Vaishnavism, we have, Krishna -> Balarāma, and then Balarāma -> Vāsudeva, Sankarsana, Pradyumna, and Aniruddha.

In Islam we have God (Allāh (s.w.t.)) -> Muhammad, and then Muhammad -> ‘Ali, Fatir (i.e. Fatima), Hasan, and Husayn.

If we want to add Samba, we add Muhsin.

Either way the correlation is clear. ‘Ali seems more like a "disguised" or veiled Incarnation (i.e. by Maya, the ism, or the hijab) then a "personal" Incarnation. But even Krishna in the Gita speaks of being veiled by His Divine Maya.

> Veiled by My creative power (yogamaya) I am not revealed to all. This bewildered world knows Me not, the unborn, the unchanging. [[Gita Society](http://www.gita-society.com/backup/hare_krishna.htm)]

The idea that God (the ma'na) is a "veiled" "Incarnation" who appears concealed by a second divinity called the ism or hijab, is an Islamic one, possessed by a sect called the Nuṣayrī‐ʿAlawīs.

Comment: Lord Vishnu has incarnated in many Yugas.. for eg. He manifested as Narasimha, Varaha etc.. in Satya Yuga; Rama, Parashurama, etc.. in Treta Yuga; Krishna, Dwaipayana Vyasa etc.. in Dwapara Yuga; Pramiti, Kalki etc.. in KaliYuga...

Comment: Hi @Tezz, it doesn't make sense for the Lord to incarnate in the Satya Yuga (i.e. during the Garden of Eden phase), because there are no problems to fix...

Comment: Well, there can be many problems in Satya Yuga.. eg in Satya Yuga people have long life span and higher ascetic powers.. and this can cause some to acquire boon from Gods... and when power comes, arrogance rises... so there is again need of incarnations...(Analogously, it's like Heaven is a place where there is Happiness.. but there can also be Dukkha in heaven because it is also sometimes attacked by Daityas....)

Comment: "Further, we might notice that there, is no incarnation of Vishnu in the Sattya Age and the explanation of this is clear enough; for as that age corresponds to Buddhi, which is characterised by the single idea of the oneness of the Supreme Purusha, the question of a conflict of opinion does not arise. Hence it is only in the last three ages, which correspond to Mind-energy and Ether, characterised by duality, that we have room for difference of opinion."

Comment: I stand by the idea that there is no need for an intervention, and thus Incarnation, in an age where there is no intellectual disunity, and therefore, physical strife. This would contradict the Bhagavad Gita: "for the sake of... I incarnate Myself age after age."

Comment: By the way the above quote was taken from this page: https://www.narach.com/philosophy/incarnations_and_ages_of_time.htm

Comment: What do you mean by Vaishnava incarnation? Did you mean human? All the incarnations are vaishnava. Narasimha is a perfect incarnation. Because there was a need to help his bhakta.  Chaturbhuja doesn't mean four people. It means four armed. Incarnating with the three other is not a necessity. There are incarnations of Vishnu in Satya yuga too. Also there are many incarnations of Vishnu.

Comment: Hi @SreeCharan, please see the Narach website I'm linking, they break down the incarnations into different systems. The only two "Vaishnava system" incarnations are Rama and Krishna, which is pretty unironic. But I would argue via Theosophy that the three Yuga incarnations are Rama, Krishna, and Kalki. I know that catur-bhuja literally means four-armed but it's pretty explicit that the four-armed form of Vishnu entails "killing demons" and that whenever this happens, Vishnu is accompanied by three co-incarnations, AKA his four arms.

Comment: Notice how, in Gaudiya Vaishnavism for example, when Vishnu is sporting alone in Heaven, he has two arms. This is his primordial form when he is one or whole, this is the equivalent of Ramanuja's Para Vāsudeva. Yet when Vishnu leaves Goloka/Vaikuntha, he has four arms, why? Why also, does he suddenly have three brothers or three co-incarnations? Because he's in his four-armed form and is about to kill demons.

Comment: I am aware that Narasimha is a perfect incarnation and I suppose that would throw a wrench in my theory. But I still really only consider the human incarnations to be the three appearances, since "man is made in God's image and all that." Furthermore, Narasimha's incarnation occurs way after Matsya's incarnation, and Matsya's incarnation occurs after the Satya Yuga, as per my Garden of Eden arguments above. I would also like to stress again, the pointless of having an incarnation when there are no demons to fight.

Comment: Fighting demons is not the only reason of incarnations. Saving the needy is also the reason.

Comment: Again, maybe not to press this point too much, but since (in the Satya Yuga), everything is perfect, there is no need for an incarnation. If we take the Bible's depiction of the Satya Yuga ("Garden of Eden"), we find that men and women lived in harmony and obeyed God, that's all there was. In such an "ideal" place, I don't see why God would need to incarnate to save the needy or annihilate demons, let alone correct disparate philosophies and views. This doesn't make any sense. It seems like the Jain "wish-fulfilling" trees were present during the Satya Yuga, such that human didn't even need—

Comment: to practice animal husbandry or farming. It's only after Adam (Manu) leaves the Satya Yuga that he begins to practice farming. Furthermore the Matsya incarnation who helps the second Manu (Noah), takes place AFTER the Satya Yuga, not before. Interestingly enough, the description of Armageddon in the Bible closely parallels the end of the Kali Yuga and the re-establishment of the Satya Yuga ("Garden of Eden"). I suppose humanity has a primordial religious tradition, after all.

Comment: Muhammed, Jesus etc are not a part of the Hindu pantheon. Adam adn Eve are not part of Hinduism's mythology. This site cannot answer Q's that compare religions or their respective Gods. Remove those portions of your Q if you want this to be answered properly.

Comment: But you must admit that Manu is a part of Hindu mythology, and that the Satya Yuga is, as well. All I'm saying is that the Satya Yuga roughly correlates with Gan Eden, and that the Vaivasvata Manu roughly correlates with the Abrahamic Noah. I mean, Noah escapes a giant deluge after God tells him to build a boat, and Vaivasvata Manu escape a giant deluge... also after God tells him to build a boat. How are the two different?

Comment: For example the Indian Kama is roughly correlated with Cupid, the Indian Hanuman with the Chinese Monkey King, the Indian Indra with Zeus, the Indian Narasimha with the Lion King, and so on and so forth. I don't mean to reduce these ideas to pure tropes, but some of these resemblances are uncanny. Even the description of Lord Narayana or Brahma lying down the primeval and dark waters before the creation begins, accords exactly with how God is described in the Bible before the creation begins (in Genesis).

Comment: That are some other correlates that I could add about the Chinese Yellow Emperor, the Mahdi, the Muslim Jesus, the Muslim Antichrist, and Muhammad, but I won't because it has to do with Jainism and it would just be opening Pandora's Box.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously my answer is fairly obvious, I believe that the three Incarnations of the Lord in those three millenniums are: Rama in Treta, Krishna in Dvapara, and Kalki in Kali. It simply makes sense. From a Theosophical point of view, the Buddha wouldn't be an Incarnation of the Lord, but rather an individual on the Eighth Rung.

On an unrelated note, and once again referencing [this page](https://www.narach.com/philosophy/incarnations_and_ages_of_time.htm), it seems that the principle idea of incarnation is to rid the world of false notions regarding God.

> In the opinion of the present writer they refer principally to true and false ideas concerning the Supreme Purusha himself; and if we agree that all evil action arises from evil thought, and there can be no greater evil thought than false ideas regarding the Supreme Creator of life, the establishment of Truth in connection with the Supreme means the establishment of Righteousness in every direction. [[Incarnations and Ages of Time](https://www.narach.com/philosophy/incarnations_and_ages_of_time.htm)]

A clear progression can be seen: ignorance (wrong views) -> wrong thoughts -> wrong actions. Incidentally... this is exactly what the Buddha taught. Perhaps then, we can see that Buddhism is not so discontinuous from Hinduism as was previously thought...

In my opinion, the appearance of Jesus seems to represent a clear stand-in for the "Vishnu guna-avatar." Since Christ is explicitly represented as "Incarnating," perhaps the second coming of Christ is really the coming of Kalki. Perhaps it's the "return of the Vishnu aspect." I've previously mused that the Buddha, Jesus, and Muhammad (s.a.w.) are actually guna-avataras. [This website](https://grahamhancock.com/dmisrab6/) believe that the present Kali Age actually began in 600 BC. Perhaps the Buddha is symbolically Brahma, played by the Buddha, Jesus is symbolically Vishnu (hence the emphasis on "Incarnation" in the Christian religion), played by Dattatreya, and Muhammad (s.a.w.) is symbolically Shiva (after all, Muhammad (s.a.w.) claimed that his arrival coincided with the end of the world), played by Narada.

But from another perspective, we could say that each of the [Abrahamic religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrahamic_religions) represents a guna, especially since the first one (Judaism), places a heavy emphasis on the God of Genesis, who floats on the deep and dark waters of creation... (Incidentally, Brahma wakes up to find only darkness and water around him... )

But then again, the notion of Tamas, and its association with darkness, water, and prakrti is a recurring theme. The Narach website I've been continuously linking touches on this theme a lot. If it is true that Matsya is the same God of the Bible who aided Noah (AKA Manu), then that means that humanity has a primordial religious tradition grounded in God, and not necessarily in sectarian division.

Back to the ignorance issue, I agree with the Narach author (his name is Akash Thadani, I believe) that wrong thoughts or wrong perceptions are the greatest evil, since they lead to wrong actions. Simply put, incorrect views regarding the Greatest Object, AKA God, would be the greatest wrong thought, and therefore the most evil (the greatest wrong perception). Incidentally, Islam treats disbelief or atheism as the greatest evil, and not some arbitrary action, such as murder. Similarly, Buddhism states that ignorance is the greatest evil. The Buddha explicitly refutes the belief that actions committed with the body are heavier than actions committed with the mind, furthermore ignorance is the "greatest sin."

Ignorance in Buddhism, however, is simply an inability to distinguish between the Permanent and impermanent, or in Islamic terms... God and His creation. In other words, it almost seems like the Buddhist view of ignorance, the Islamic view of disbelief, and the Hindu view of incorrect conceptions regarding God, coincide. Meaning that God's work is mainly intellectual, i.e. combating false ideas, in order to bring about unity, and therefore, peace.

---

The Nuṣayrī‐ʿAlawīs are an interesting sect. In some of the works I've read, associated with the sect, the Twelve Imams are presented as manifestations of the deity. M.A. Amir-Moezzi translates some discourses by the Imam ‘Ali that sound like proclamations of divinity, I believe these same songs are translated on the bahai-library.com website. These songs sound eerily similar to Krishna's proclamation of divinity in the Bhagavad Gita. It seems however, that Krishna's incarnation is "unveiled" while ‘Ali's is "veiled." Both say very similar things, ‘Ali says: "I am the Lord of the Ka'ba, and the month of Ramadan … the secret of the letters, the meaning of tawasin, esoteric of hawamim, the Lord of the alif-lam-mim … I am the Mahdī of all moments, and the Jesus of the Time … the High, the Most High, the Lion of the sons of Banu Ghalib. I am Ali b. Abū Talib."

Whereas Krishna says: "of the seasons I am Spring, of the Vedas I am the Sama, … I am the luck of the gambler and the strength of the strong … of sages I am Vyasa …" and so on and so forth.

Both sound like proclamations of the ma'na.